# How to count entries per day?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with download time in column "time" as a datetime and want to count the number of downloads in a day.
So the output in the example should be 
[2004-01-05  1]
[2004-01-06  11]

```
ip           time            cik    accession
12.108.130.jcf  05.01.04 17:56  1096142 0001179022-04-000019
12.108.130.jcf  06.01.04 08:31  1096142 0001179022-04-000005
12.108.130.jcf  06.01.04 08:34  1096142 0001179022-04-000006
12.108.130.jcf  06.01.04 08:34  1096142 0001179022-04-000007
12.108.130.jcf  06.01.04 08:35  1096142 0001179022-04-000008
12.108.130.jcf  06.01.04 08:36  1096142 0001179022-04-000009
12.108.130.jcf  06.01.04 08:36  1096142 0001179022-04-000010
12.108.130.jcf  06.01.04 08:36  1096142 0001179022-04-000011
12.108.130.jcf  06.01.04 08:37  1096142 0001179022-04-000012
12.108.130.jcf  06.01.04 08:39  1096142 0001179022-04-000013
12.108.130.jcf  06.01.04 08:39  1096142 0001179022-04-000014
12.108.130.jcf  06.01.04 08:40  1096142 0001179022-04-000015
```

```
df = pd.read_csv('12.108.130.jcf.csv')
df['time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.time).normalize()
df['count'] = df.groupby('time')['time'].transform('count')
df = df[['time','count']]
print(df)
```

I become an output like

```
         time                         count
0     2004-01-05 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
1     2004-01-06 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000011
```

And I can't explain where the date 1970-01-01 come from and why the format of the counts is like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a reason I have trouble to understand, the type of the `count` column is `datetime`, and `Timestamp(1)` is `'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001'`, that is the origin of Unix time + 1 microsecond.

You can revert this behavior with `df = df.astype({'count': int})`. But it's hard to reproduce the problem without the real file.

Comment: Thank you really much!! Do you have an idea how I can plot the vector ? With time at x axis and count at the y axis?

Comment: Create a new DataFrame, then plot it with matplotlib. Try something like: `df2 = DataFrame(df['count'], index=df['time']); df2.plot(); import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.show();`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not interested in align the dataframe with the counts, instead of

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('time')['time'].transform('count')
```

do only

```
df.groupby('time')['time'].count()
```

Output:

```
time
2004-05-01     1
2004-06-01    11
Name: time, dtype: int64
```